# Is it true that $G^2$ is always hamiltonian?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

Given a connected graph $G$, define $G^2$ to be a graph with same vertex set as $G$ and edge between two vertices $u$ and $v$ iff the distance between $u$ and $v$ in $G$ is at most $2$.

> Is it true that $G^2$ is always hamiltonian?

I think that I've proved it, but since I am asked to prove the corresponding result for $G^3$ instead of $G^2$, I doubt that this result is true. If it is not true, can you please give a counter example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any tree in which there is a vertex connected to at least $3$ non-leafs is a counterexample.

Assume there is a Hamiltonian cycle starting at $v$ and let $\ell_1$ and $\ell_2$ be the first two non-leaf neighbours of $v$ in the cycle, in that order. Notice that the Hamiltonian cycle must be like this: $v,\dots, \ell_1,\color{red}{\dots} \ell_2,\dots$. However the problem is that after $\ell_2$ it is no longer possible to cross over $v$ and reach the other neighbours of $v$.

(The red dots $\color{red}{\dots}$ may be a (possibly empty) sequence of leafs that are connected to $v$, I hadn't noticed it initially).

If you want a concrete example I suggest you consider the following graph:

[image] [image]

Comment: I couldn't understand, which vertex is $v$? Can you please elaborate (and label the given figure)?

Comment: $v$ is the vertex that is connected to at least $3$ non-leafs.

Comment: But then, won't it be a problem even if we consider $G^3$ instead of $G^2$? By taking at least $4$ non-leaf neighbours.

Comment: I can add a proof of the statement for $G^3$ if you want, this was just a counterexample for the statement of $G^2$. I can also add a hint if you want to solve it yourself.

Comment: No, I realized where did my proof of $G^2$ got wrong. I just want to know, why this counterexample doesn't work in that case.

Comment: It took me like 20 seconds to find a hamiltonian cycle in $G^3$ in that example

Comment: This is a good counterexample; can you explain "red dots"?

Comment: @Joffan I initially thought that $l_1$ had to go directly to $l_2$, but it can first go through the leaf neighbours of $v$

Comment: @Joffan Thanks for the pictures they are very nice ! to be honest I am not a huge fan of hosting pictures on a seperate website (imgur). I would like it if there was a workaround to just use tikz with mathjax, but I appreciate it nontheless :) . I guess imgur is reliable, although I don't know enough on the subject.

Comment: I just use the default setup when adding pictures on MSE, to be honest I couldn't tell you what site they live on. I'm a big fan of using $\ell$ instead of $l$ as you can tell. :-)

Comment: Well if you read what the button does it seems to create a link for the pictures. This seems related https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90342/any-details-about-stack-imgur-com